# Unused typescript warning is actually used

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 9 app.  When I build I get the error:

```
WARNING in *projectpath*\src\app\DataModel\Enums.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
```

I have searched this error and there are plenty of pages on it but I don't think they are the same situation as I've tried to fix it from that and it doesn't work.  Most say to remove it from that section or to update an older file format but neither of those seem to be the case here.  That file contains a bunch of string literals (it's basically a holder for them).  The contents look like this:

```
type TaskTrigger =
  'OnceNow' |
  'OnceLater' |
  'Recurring' |
  'OnPublish';

... other types...

type DragTypes =
  'model' |
  'directory';
```

I looked at my `tsconfig.app.json` file and it does include that file.  Here is the files section of that:

```
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts",
    "app/DataModel/Enums.ts"
  ],
```

However, when I remove it from the array then I get a bunch of build errors about those types not being defined and the project won't build.  So obviously it's used but it's not imported anywhere so it's giving the warning.  How do I make the warning go away?

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry figured it out.  For anyone else that runs into the same issue, you need to export the types from the file, then import them in the other files.  So my Enums.ts file now looks like this:

```
export type TaskTrigger =
  'OnceNow' |
  'OnceLater' |
  'Recurring' |
  'OnPublish';

... other types...

export type DragTypes =
  'model' |
  'directory';
```

Then in the other files instead of just using them, you get an import statement like this:

```
import {RecurrenceEndType, RecurrencePeriod, TaskTrigger} from './Enums';
```

That import causes the file to be referenced, and then you can take it out of the files in `tsconfig.app.json` and viola, warning gone!